# How to populate a list<list<T>> with 100 empty List<T>s without a loop?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have the following list:

```
List<List<BaseTile>> retVal = new List<List<BaseTile>>();
```

I need to populate it with 100 empty `List<BaseTile>`s (then I will populate them with the things I need)

The way to do it is just:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    retval.add(new List<BaseTile>());
```

I'm pretty sure that there is some [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) trick to do it without a loop, and I'm curious what is it. I tried:

```
retVal.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat<List<BaseTile>>(new List<BaseTile>(),100));
```

But unfortunately it doesn't do what I want, because all the lists in the list reference to the same list (which makes a lot of sense, because that is the meaning of Repeat :) )

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(_ => new List<T>())`

Comment: Next, on Silly Coding Tricks: using LINQ in the one place where a loop is actually *more* declarative. ;)

Comment: You can't do it "without" the loop. All you can do is **hide** the loop, by adding extra abstraction and indirection. This, IMO, makes the code *worse*, not better.

Comment: I was interested not because it's very important for my code, but because i just wanted to learn how to do it ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took one look at

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  retval.add(new List<BaseTile>());
```

And understood it straight away while

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(_ => new List<T>())
```

Is not obvious.

K.I.S.S.

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerable.Range(1, 100)` can "fake" a `for` loop. Then you can `Select` off of the resulting `IEnumerable<int>`, ignoring the index.

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(_ => new List<BaseTile>()).ToList();
```

If you just want to use the 100 empty `List<T>` objects in some other way (i.e. not in a `List<List<T>>`) then omit `ToList()` and enumerate them yourself.